# Why is A Clockwork Orange considered great?

Tags: a-clockwork-orange

A few months ago I decided to watch *A Clockwork Orange*, as I was only inspired by its IMDB ratings and reviews and the generally high public opinion about the movie. So I was expecting a great movie. I won't lie, but it seldom happens that I cannot tolerate at least the first half of a movie, but in this case, it happened. I couldn't watch it more than 30 minutes, and those 30 minutes I was wondering what is the story, why is this nude and violent. It felt overly violent and sexually explicit to me in the first half hour and I couldn't see how those aspects contributed to the story. This movie made my mind go crazy and irritated like no other movie, not even *A serbian movie*.

So I'd like to know why it is regarded such a masterpiece. Or does it take a drastic change after 40 minutes or something which I missed and should I give it one more try, which I am very reluctant to? Or did I just miss something about it that better explains how those to me rather repelling aspects of the movie contributed to its quality?

Comment: Have you considered reading some of the large amounts of literature about it?

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question a little to make it sound a little less opinionated (even if it still is quite a bit) while keeping the original intent.

Comment: *This movie made my mind go crazy and irritated like no other movie* – Making some assumptions about the number of movies you consumed, this actually is a remarkable achievement and shows that *A Clockwork Orange* is a very powerful movie. As @Catija [already hinted](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420/catija), a good movie or any piece of art must not necessarily be enjoyable. Think, e.g., about anti-war movies: if they are enjoyable (other than from a point of view that is purely appreciating the art), they most likely did something wrong.

Answer (score 16):

There are many reasons, probably too many to list. But here are a few to start (although without citation)

- it presents a credible but bleak vision of the near future
- the scenes of violence are brutal, yet also choreographed as well as any dance scene (and with perfectly matching music, too)
- the character arc of the protagonist as he goes from thug to victim to political pawn (you actually feel sorry for him)
- the sly humorous digs at bureaucracy
- the gorgeous cinematography
- in fact, the use of classical music throughout to set tone (I know, it's not even the first Kubrick movie to do this, but it is a great exemplar of this technique)

That said, it is not for everyone. Don't force yourself to watch it if you aren't enjoying it.

Comment: Very nicely put. I think it's interesting how some often seem to think that a "good film" is one that everyone will enjoy watching.

Comment: Exactly. I'm glad I watched Citizen Kane, once without commentary and once with, and while I found it ponderous and dull, I cannot deny its influence on later films.

Comment: Personally I don't sorry for the protagonist at all. It triggers me how at the ending scene of "Un prophète" Luciani crawls back, beaten - he was a monster but something makes me feel pity. I can not find any sympathy to the protagonist of "A Clockwork Orange".